# heroku rails application build failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing builder 3.0.4
       Installing journey 1.0.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing rack 1.4.5
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing arel 3.0.3
       Installing bootstrap-sass 2.0.0
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.42
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.2
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing sass 3.4.9
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing rack-cache 1.2
       Installing activesupport 3.2.21
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
       Installing sprockets 2.2.3
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
       Installing uglifier 1.2.3
       Installing activemodel 3.2.21
       Installing rdoc 3.12.2
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing actionpack 3.2.21
       Installing activerecord 3.2.21
       Installing activeresource 3.2.21
       Installing actionmailer 3.2.21
       Installing railties 3.2.21
       Installing pg 0.12.2
       Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
       Installing jquery-rails 2.0.1
       Installing rails 3.2.21
       Installing sass-rails 3.2.4
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (17.28s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/Rakefile:7)
       rake aborted!
       PGError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__971333411375098380__prepare__1628314258144706216__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_88f0e85760141090706776361438977e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !     Attempted to access a nonexistent database:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
# gem 'pg', '0.12.2' #seems to not work try below
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'pry-remote'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:key => "value",
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.1'

# Test gems on Macintosh OS X 
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end
```

Comment: which DB do you want to use? is it pg or mysql?

Comment: did you added heroku addons? see my answer and go to the link. Hopefully you will get answer.

Comment: it didnt realy work i've edited the question to contain my gemfile

Comment: see my answer. do you added any pgsql addon in heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Your log, there are issue with your DB. By default heroku support PG but you can use mysql or other DB. If you want to use PG, then add **pg** gem into your gem file. Like:

```
gem 'pg'
```

FYI, there are no relation with database.yml and heroku ;) But you need to add postgree addons to achieve your application up and runing. Follow: [Postgre](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

I hope you are now get full idea about DB and Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set up a production database yet, and properly configured your application to look for the corresponding `ENV` variable (specifically the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` variable) for the production database.

See the [Heroku Postgres docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) for all the setup details, [Ruby section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby) of the documentation for details on this setup in Rails.